# Cannot find Typescript module even though tsc successfully manages to resolve it

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface, ts-node, oclif

I have a Node.js project written in Typescript which is expected to run as a CLI, and am having trouble to import a module located out of the `node_modules` directory using an absolute path (relative paths work fine). It might be important to mention that I am using the [oclif framework](https://github.com/oclif/oclif) for building my CLI.

My project is organized as follows:

```
cli
 |--node_modules
 |--src
     |--my-module.ts
     |--subdir
          |--index.ts
```

Within `my-module.ts` I have:

```
 export class MyClass {
     myClassFcn(s: string) {
         return 'result'
     }
 }
```

The `index.ts` script contains something like:

```
 import {MyClass} = require('my-module')
```

When I try to execute my app with ts-node, I get

```
(node:10423) [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] Error Plugin: cli: Cannot find module 'my-module'
    module: @oclif/config@1.6.17
    task: toCached
    plugin: cli
    root: /home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli
    Error Plugin: cli: Cannot find module 'my-module'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli/src/commands/create/index.ts:5:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
        at Module.m._compile (/home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:403:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:406:12)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    module: @oclif/config@1.6.17
    task: toCached
    plugin: my-plugin
    root: /home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli
```

What I can't understand is that when I run `tsc --traceResolution` the module is correctly resolved:

```
======== Module name 'my-module' was successfully resolved to '/home/eschmidt/Workspace/cli/src/my-module.ts'. ========
```

My `tsconfig.json` file contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "pretty": true,
    "rootDirs": [
      "./src/"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this issue, or at least suggest where to look for further help. In case more details are needed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running `ts-node` from within the `subdir` directory, and `tsc` from your root project directory ? Does importing from `'../my-module'` work instead ?

Comment: As far as I understand, `ts-node` is registered from within the `oclif` framework, and called automatically when I run the sh script I have in `/bin` and don't have any transpiled JS in the `lib` directory. I run `tsc` with yarn from the project root directory. Importing from a relative path as in '../my-module' works just fine, as expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was due to the fact that although both tsc and ts-node use `baseUrl` for absolute path resolution, neither of them perform any type of actual mapping from absolute to relative paths in the generated Javascript code. In other words, both the transpiled JS files and the code produced internally by ts-node end up having:

```
import  {MyClass} = require('my-module')
```

whereas I was expecting them to contain something like:

```
import  {MyClass} = require('../my-module')
```

which prevented node's module loader from finding the module. ts-node also did not work, I believe, because there was simply no tsconfig.json file to indicate the path mappings.

Although confusing IMO, and not properly documented, this is expected behavior, though, as discussed [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/294). As of now, absolute to relative path mapping is not supported by Typescript (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479).

In order to avoid the situation known as path hell, which means having very deep relative import paths, I found [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) and [tsmodule-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@momothepug/tsmodule-alias) to be very useful. These modules alter the behavior of the module loader so that it automatically maps aliases to relative paths.

For more information about the problem, refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-393676653) on Github.

Comment: Kudos for the big research and Gitlab posts. Helped me to understand that this is a bug-feature that looks like it's gonna work same as options in jsconfig. Only it doesn't.
Hit us up in here if you've maybe found some solution in these 6 years.

Comment: Happy to hear you found this useful. Unfortunately I haven't had the time/interest to look for better solutions. Also worth highlighting the fact that at the time of writing I was working on a CLI app, and one of the main reasons for me to use TS was the existence of oclif, which would allow me to prototype fast. With time, however, I concluded that there were more suitable options, and ended up abandoning TS and migrating to Go.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that may be relevant is to run node with `NODE_PATH=dist node dist/index.js`. This essentially specifies to `node` what path each absolute import (relative to `baseUrl`) should use

Comment: I have been banging my head against the wall for the last two days. I simply could not get my app to run due to `Cannot find module` (my own module), even though `tsc --traceResolution` was all happy. I have the following setup: `myproj/src/...`. The `tsconfig.json` I have set `"outDir": "dist"` and `"rootDir": "."`. Simply adding the following to `package.json/Scripts` solved the problem `"start": "NODE_PATH=dist/src node dist/src/app.js"`. Thanks for the tip!!!!