# TypeScript: How can a module be 'found' but not resolved? What does this have to do with 'noResolution'?

Tags: typescript

When I run tsc in the 'proj' directory with --traceResolution, I see the module 'foo' is "successfully resolved" but not "found":

```
======== Module name 'foo' was successfully resolved to 'C:/dev/ts-options/typings/foo/index.d.ts'. ========

main.ts(1,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'foo'.
```

Setting `"noResolve": true` in tsconfig.compilerOptions makes the error go away. But I'm supr-confused!

Question 1: What is the difference between "resolution" and "finding"? I thought these were synonyms

Question 2: Why does 'noResolve' affect this behavior? What does noResolve actually do? TS [compiler options docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) say "Do not add triple-slash references or module import targets to the list of compiled files." but I don't know what that means.

With this directory structure

- /c/dev/ts-options/

  - typings/

    - foo

      - index.d.ts
  - proj **this is where I'm running tsc**

    - tsconfig.json
    - main.ts

proj/tsconfig.json (problem is fixed if I change noResolve to false):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "types": [],
        "outDir": "../out",
        "paths": {
            "foo": [
                "../typings/foo"
            ],
        },
        "noResolve": true
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

proj/main.ts:

`import foo  from "foo"`

typings/foo/index.d.ts:

```
declare function foo(num: number): number;
export default foo;
```

### Update

Two solutions:

- Set noResolve: false
- OR add "../typings" to the "include" section in the tsconfig

My guess is that there is a concept of a "compilation unit" such that:

- with `noResolve: false` then the compilation unit can grow dynamically as TS follows `import`s.
- With `noResolve: true`, then the compilation unit is fixed to
  something like `tsconfig.baseUrl/** + (tsconfig.include -    tsconfi.exclude)` .
- When a file is outside the compilation unit then TS can 'resolve' an import (find out the path to a .d.ts/.ts/.tsx file) but won't 'find' it (actually read the file).

This still doesn't really make sense to me,  though. What's the point of 'resolving' to a location one knows one won't be able to 'find'?

Comment: Note: this is not the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593774/cannot-find-typescript-module-even-though-tsc-successfully-manages-to-resolve-it, which was about a runtime failure.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of this issue is an incorrect named path in the `paths` option in `tsconfig.json`. You are defining a path named `foo` to point to "../typings/foo" relative to the project's root, but that is not correct because as it translates to a non-existent path:

Assuming the `proj` directory is this:

`C:/dev/ts-options`

then combined with the defined `foo` path it expands to:

`C:/dev/ts-options/../typings/foo`

which results in the non-existent path:

`C:/dev/rp-build/node/rp-cli/test/fixtures/src/typescript/typings/foo`.

The resolving does find it eventually by going down all the directories but the `import` uses the `foo` named path that gets translated to the above wrong full path.

So there are two solutions, either you correct the `foo` path definition in the tsconfig.json, or use a relative path to the main.ts of foo/index.d.ts in the `import` statement like this:

```
import foo from "../../../whatever/typings/foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it doesn't seem to be correct or fully answer what I was asking. The path resolution is correct: you may have missed the part of my question where I said where I'm running 'tsc' (edited the question to make this clearer). Also, this answer doesn't address 'Question 1' or 'Question 2', which were what I wanted to know.

Comment: It is correct for your question, before you edited it and changed it. Also why did you edit my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no memory of this and am not working on this stuff anymore. I'll vote your answer up