# cannot find module nodejs debugger

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have project in typescript. I am trying to debug with preLaunchTask to
transpile typescript into js in folder build.

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "es2019", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowJs": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

this is my launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug TypeScript in Node.js",
        "preLaunchTask": "typescript",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/api/src/index.ts",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "outFiles": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/api/build/**/*.js"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

and this is my tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "api/tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "typescript"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\api\build\index.js
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'database/createConnection
```

createConnection.js is located in **build/database**

Clearly I have something with paths, because
**__importDefault(require("database/createConnection"));** this is line
of code in index.js but not quite sure where to look at.
Can you help me with this issue? I have found this similar
topic [cannot find typescript module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593774/cannot-find-typescript-module-even-though-tsc-successfully-manages-to-resolve-it) . It seems that transpilling typescript didn't add base path to te imports.

EDIT:
I have tried install module-alias
and set in package.json

```
 "_moduleAliases": {
    "*": "./"
  }
```

then I added this line
on beginning of index.js

`require('module-alias/register');`

but it doesn't work...
I am also experimenting with
link-module-alias but can't make symlink * work.
I need all paths with default prefix ./

Comment: Can you try using require("./database/createConnection") instead ? (just added ./ at the beginning of path)

Comment: It works but I need it to add recursively inside all files, must be way to make it automatically from typescript conversion.

Comment: Then, using require.main.require could help you, so you would be able to have the same route for all your files, however, it's not exactly what you wanted.
Hope it can help while you are waiting for an answer :)

Comment: How I can use require.main.require?

Comment: There is nothing to add, just replacing require by require.main.require will work